# django - adding a counter for every ManyToMany field added

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many, relationship

i have these models:

```
#model.py

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name",max_length=50, blank=True)
    ...
    ...

class Activity(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField("Act. name",max_length=150)
    price = models.DecimalField("price", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default=0)
    count = models.IntegerField("Count", default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.label)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Activities"


class Invoice(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today())
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity)
    ....
    ....
```

while creating a new Invoice instance on admin, i can select the many to many fields 'activities', but i'd like to have an additional counter (eg. an IntegerField) as an Invoice field to count and save the quantity of each activity added to my Invoice instance. Is this possible?

thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 1):

You could have a field on the model and override the save method

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today())
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity)
    activity_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def save(self):
       self.activity_count = self.activities.count()
       super(Invoice, self).save()
```

Comment: that's not what i need: suppose that for an Invoice instance, I add two activities as m2m fields. Now for each one of 'em, i need a counter, not a total counter of how many m2m fields are added to that instance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to count for each activity?

Comment: for each 'Activity' added to an Invoice instance, i need to count the amount of that activity.